# "come away a feeling" or "come away feeling", which one is more appropriate?

Tags: word-choice

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?t=52)

> And my goal is for you to come away
>   feeling like you could have invented
>   calculus yourself. That is, cover all

[feeling](http://countable) is countable.

So, is "come away a feeling" more appropriate?

Answer (score -1):

In this particular context, "come away" means "Be left with a specified feeling, impression, or result after doing something". See also [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/come), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-away-with-something) and others. Cambridge uses

> *I came away empty-handed.*

as an example.

So "feeling" is not a noun, but an adjective. You will be feeling like something.